# Progress bar between two dates from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm looking to make a progress bar that advances between two dates that have been set stored on my MySQL.

i saw some ways with javascript but didn't worked to me... i have low experience with sql and i will apreciate some way to catch date from my DB and use on this while to build a table with progressbar

**My PHP code with connection MySQL + While**

```
<?php
include 'conexao/conexao.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trabalho_v2";
$busca = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);


while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($busca))
{


    $trab_id = $dados['trabalho_id'];
    $cliente = $dados['Nome_cliente'];
    $tema = $dados['titulo_trabalho'];
    $recebido = $dados['trabalho_recebido'];
    $entrega = $dados['data_entregar'];
    $tipo = $dados['tipo_trabalho'];

?>
            <!-- // TABLE -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $trab_id ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <?php echo $cliente ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <?php echo $tema ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="progress-wrapper">
                    <div class="progress-info">
                      <div class="progress-percentage">
                        <span>60%</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-primary" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%; height:40px;"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  Date 01: <?php echo $recebido ?><br>
                  Date 02: <?php echo $entrega ?>
                  
                  
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $tipo ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <a href="editarTrabalho.php?id=<?php echo $trab_id ?>" role=button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
} ?>
```

**- What data will determine the percentage?**

Start: DATE 1  =  $recebido 
End:   DATA 2  = $entrega

Comment: Where exactly are things going wrong then?

Comment: What data will determine the percentage? Please show specific examples.

Comment: The start is  DATE 1 = $recebido and DATA 2 $entrega = the end (100%)

Comment: Adyson, i'm looking for a way to consume the data from MySQL in a javascript code

Comment: You have to think about the objective first, then about the way you're going to implement it. Why do you think you need JavaScript? Your code doesn't show any to begin with. Have you made an attempt yourself? If so, please share your code. You're currently setting the `width` property of the `#progressbar` using inline CSS. You could calculate its value in PHP and output it to the document. What have you tried so far to get the distance between the two dates?

Answer (score 2):

**i found this solution with pure php without javascript:**

```
   <?php 


              // ESSA PARTE É PARA O CONTADOR DE DIAS
              $data_entrega = $dados['data_entregar'];
              $data_recebe  = date("Y-m-d");
              
              // transforma a data do formato BR para o formato americano, ANO-MES-DIA
              $data_entrega = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data_entrega)));
              $data_recebe = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', $data_recebe)));
              
              // converte as datas para o formato timestamp
              $d1 = strtotime($data_entrega); 
              $d2 = strtotime($data_recebe);
              
              // verifica a diferença em segundos entre as duas datas e divide pelo número de segundos que um dia possui
              $dataFinal = ($d1 - $d2) /86400;
              
              // caso a data 2 seja maior que a data 1, finaliza pq entende que passou da data
              if($dataFinal < 0)
                  $dataFinal = "fim";
        
             
             
              
            
            ?>
```